# How I undo someone else approved edit?

Tags: support

I had a question with an edit suggestion added by an user with lots of rejected edits (much more than his approved edits).

The suggestion was rejected a couple times by experienced users, but some people that probably were not paying attention approved it.

The edit that was suggested broke my question formatting BADLY (it became unreadable on my device).

I fixed it by coping my old markdown and pasting again in a new edit, but I looked here on meta how to do it correctly and could not find it (all other question I found is how to undo your own edits or undo your own edit suggestions).

So, how I undo someone else edit that was erroneously approved? (even better, how I tag that it was erroneously approved, so that the people that approved it get a warning that they approved something without looking properly?)

Comment: You can go to the revisions page and click *"rollback"* on the version you want to restore to. As for *"tag that it was erroneously approved"*, I think you would have to raise a custom moderator flag if you wanted any further action taken.